# Redeploying a Liberty .war app running in Liberty Docker

Tags: docker, websphere-liberty

I am using Liberty Docker version to test an alternative to Liberty boilerplate in BlueMix: https://hub.docker.com/_/websphere-liberty/

Creating the image is a slow process. I wonder if there is a recommended approach to re-deploy an application war. Currently I have to recreate the docker file every time I make a change in my App.

The app is deployed in /config/apps/ directory along with some shared libraries , bootstrap.properties file, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you actually looked at `Usage` section on that page?
In the point 1) it is described:

> A .WAR file can therefore be mounted in the dropins directory of this
>   server and run. The following example starts a container in the
>   background running a .WAR file from the host file system

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:9080 -p 443:9443 \
  -v /tmp/DefaultServletEngine/dropins/Sample1.war:/config/dropins/Sample1.war \
  websphere-liberty:webProfile7
```

This should allow you to dynamically update the application without any need to rebuild the image.

You have there also other examples which show how to mount whole config folder.